# Excel VBA verificar o conteudo de duas celulas

Tags: vba

Bom dia.

Estou tentando criar alguns modulos em excel para me ajudar no trabalho e um dos modulos que criei troca todas as letras acentuadas e caracteres especiais de uma "cell" por letras sem acento e substitutos para os caracteres especiais. Vide exemplo abaixo:

```
Cell A1= "Essa peça de roupa custa R$59,99 somente este mês."
Cell A2= "Essa peca de roupa custa RS59,99 somente este mes."
```

Preciso criar um modulo que cheque se oque está na "Cell"A1 está de acordo com a "cell" A2 mesmo sem os acentos e caracteres especiais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro que vc crie uma função com as regras de substituição de caractéres com acentos. Não sei como vc escreveu este código, mas imaginei algo assim, estruturado como uma função para melhor manuseio de variáveis:

```
Public Function SemAcentos(t As String)

    t = Replace(t, "ç", "c")
    t = Replace(t, "à", "a")
    t = Replace(t, "á", "a")
    t = Replace(t, "ã", "a")
    t = Replace(t, "â", "a")
    t = Replace(t, "é", "e")
    t = Replace(t, "ê", "e")
    t = Replace(t, "í", "i")
    t = Replace(t, "õ", "o")
    t = Replace(t, "ó", "o")
    t = Replace(t, "ú", "u")

    ' ...todas as demais regras de substituição de caracteres especiais!!!

    SemAcentos = t

End Function
```

Dessa forma, vc pode retirar os acentos da Cell A1 e imediatamente compará-la com a Cell A2, algo assim:

```
Sub macro1()

    If SemAcentos(Range("A1").Value) = Range("A2").valuie Then
        MsgBox "Verdadeiro"
    Else
        MsgBox "Falso"
        End If

End Sub
```

Ou, como vc criou uma função, pode usá-la diretamente numa célula da planilha, usando em combinação com a fórmula SE, por exemplo:

```
=SE(SemAcentos(A1)=A2;VERDADEIRO;FALSO)
```